# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting '(' in C:\xampp\htdocs\vft_forum\admin\admin_forum\poster.php on line 189

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have got that error when trying to open my files after adding some line on on the file. here are my codes

```
if($topic=="WINDOWS"){?>

    <script>
        window.location = 'home.php';
    </script>   
<?php }elseif($topic=="MAC"){?>

    <script>
        window.location = 'mac.php';
    </script>   
<?php }elseif($topic=="LINUX"){?>

    <script>
        window.location = 'linux.php';
    </script>   
<?php }elseif($topic=="ANDROID"){?>

    <script>
        window.location = 'android.php';
    </script>   
<?php  }elseif($topic=="PROGRAMMING"){?>

    <script>
        window.location = 'program.php';
    </script>   
<?php }elseif($topic=="HARDWARE"){?>

    <script>
        window.location = 'hardware.php';
    </script>   
<?php }elseif($topic=="IOS"){?>

    <script>
        window.location = 'ios.php';
    </script>   
<?php }else {?>

    <script>
        window.location = 'msoffice.php';
    </script>   
<?php  } 
}?>
```

the error occurred on line that started with HARDWARE. I have tried to check but i couldint find that error. could some one help me with this? thanks in advance

Comment: one extra `}` in very last

Comment: to much lines in you code, you can write it cleaner and smarter. use http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
switch ($topic) {
    case "WINDOWS":
        $url = 'home.php';
        break;
    case "MAC":
        $url = 'mac.php';
        break;
    //more cases ......
    default:
        $url = 'msoffice.php';
        break;
}
?>
 <script>
   window.location = '<?php print $url; ?>';
 </script>
```

Comment: +10 because your answer is good too.

Answer (score 2):

Have an `'}'` in the very end. Remove that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. but now im  getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Comment: Sorry mate its my mistake i clicked on a wrong post. my apologies @Anant

Comment: @oedward38  then correct it.

Answer (score 2):

***Suggestion:- use `switch()` cases instead of this much lines of code.***

BTW properly formated code is:-

```
if($topic=="WINDOWS"){?>

    <script>
        window.location = 'home.php';
    </script>   
<?php }elseif($topic=="MAC"){?>

    <script>
        window.location = 'mac.php';
    </script>   
<?php }elseif($topic=="LINUX"){?>

    <script>
        window.location = 'linux.php';
    </script>   
<?php }elseif($topic=="ANDROID"){?>

    <script>
        window.location = 'android.php';
    </script>   
<?php  }elseif($topic=="PROGRAMMING"){?>

    <script>
        window.location = 'program.php';
    </script>   
<?php }elseif($topic=="HARDWARE"){?>

    <script>
        window.location = 'hardware.php';
    </script>   
<?php }elseif($topic=="IOS"){?>

    <script>
        window.location = 'ios.php';
    </script>   
<?php }else {?>

    <script>
        window.location = 'msoffice.php';
    </script>   
<?php  } ?>
```

Note:-

**1.remove the very last `}`.**

**2.Try to do proper Indenting of code.**

**3.Try to use some code-editor which will let you know automatically about these type of errors while coding itself.**